# Using mockito to test bigger services in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I started learning mockito to test my classes. I know how to do this with small classes with one, maybe 2 mocks, but I have a problem when my service is much bigger. For example, I have service

```
public class ShoppingListService {

    Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList = new HashMap<>();
    List<MealInfo> meals = new ArrayList<>();
    UserInfoService userInfoService;
    DietMealsService dietMealsService;
    UserRepository userRepository;
    User user;

    @Autowired
    public ShoppingListService(UserInfoService userInfoService, DietMealsService dietMealsService,UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userInfoService = userInfoService;
        this.dietMealsService = dietMealsService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Map<Ingredient,Long> createShoppingList(){
        user = userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(userInfoService.getUser().getLogin(),userInfoService.getUser().getPassword()).get();
        shoppingList.clear();
        meals.clear();
        meals = user.getDiet().getMeals();
        meals=dietMealsService.adjustIngredients(meals);
        for (MealInfo meal : meals) {
            meal.getMeal().getIngredients().forEach(s -> {
                if(shoppingList.containsKey(s.getIngredient()))
                    shoppingList.put(s.getIngredient(), s.getWeight()+shoppingList.get(s.getIngredient()));
                else
                shoppingList.put(s.getIngredient(),s.getWeight());
            });
        }
        return shoppingList;
    }
}
```

and I want to test method `createShoppingList`.

Should I create few instances and mock every field except shoppingList and meals and then create 1 or 2 instances of ingredients, meals and after use when->then like this?

```
@Test
public void createShoppingList() {

    //GIVEN
    Ingredient pineapple = new Ingredient().builder().name("Pineapple").caloriesPer100g(54F).carbohydratePer100g(13.6F).fatPer100g(0.2F).proteinPer100g(0.8F).build();
    Ingredient watermelon = new Ingredient().builder().name("Watermelon").caloriesPer100g(36F).carbohydratePer100g(8.4F).fatPer100g(0.1F).proteinPer100g(0.6F).build();

    IngredientWeight pineappleWithWeight...

    //after this create Meal, MealInfo, Diet...

}
```

Below other classes:

```
public class MealInfo implements Comparable<MealInfo>{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate date;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id")
    private Meal meal;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "diet_meal_info", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "meal_info_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "diet_id"))
    private List<Diet> diet;

    public MealInfo(LocalDate date, String description, Meal meal) {
        this.date = date;
        this.name = description;
        this.meal = meal;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MealInfo o) {
        return getName().compareTo(o.getName());
    }
}


public class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "meal_ingredient", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
    private List<IngredientWeight> ingredients;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;
    private String imageUrl;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "meal_category", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private Set<Category> category;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MealInfo> mealInfo;
    private Integer calories;

    public Meal(MealForm mealForm) {
        this.name = mealForm.getName();
        this.description = mealForm.getDescription();
        this.imageUrl = mealForm.getImageUrl();
        this.category = mealForm.getCategory();
    }
}

public class IngredientWeight {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_weight_id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;
    private Long weight;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "meal_ingredient", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "meal_id"))
    private Set<Meal> meals;

}

public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "calories")
    private Float caloriesPer100g;
    @Column(name = "proteins")
    private Float proteinPer100g;
    @Column(name = "carbohydrates")
    private Float carbohydratePer100g;
    @Column(name = "fat")
    private Float fatPer100g;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE},
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<IngredientWeight> ingredientWeights;

}
```

Could you write how to test this method or test implementation? Or maybe do you have any public repositories with tests bigger methods like this?

Comment: You should start by fixing the design: shoppingList, meal and user should not be instance fields. They should be local variables of the createShoppingList method. Then you should mock the three dependencies of the service.

Comment: You should mock every dependent object and inject them. Mock their behavior, like repository methods, give parameters and assert the result with what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you probably don't want the fields `user`, `shoppingList` and `meals` in your service. These fields make the service unsafe to use in a multi-threaded environment, like a web app or web service (which can be accessed by multiple clients, so multiple threads, at the same time). For example the `shoppingList` you are working on might be cleared halfway through the process if another thread enters `createShoppingList`. Instead, make these fields local variables inside the `createShoppingList` method for now. If the logic becomes too complex and your service too large, you could extract it into a separate service or a helper class which is instantiated at the start of the method call and discarded at the end of it.

I always write unit tests as white-box tests for a single class. I try to cover every branch in the code if I can. You can check this by running the tests with coverage in IntelliJ. Note that black-box tests are also very useful, they focus on 'the contract' of a component. In my opinion unit tests are usually not suited for this, since the contract of a single class is normally not very interesting for the component's functionality as a whole and can easily change if the code is refactored. I write integration (or end-to-end) tests as black box tests. This requires setting up a stubbed application environment with for example an in-memory database and maybe some external services via WireMock. I you are interested in this, look into Google's contract testing or RestAssured framework.

Some remarks about your code:

```
public Map<Ingredient,Long> createShoppingList() {

// if any of the chained methods below return null, a NullPointerException occurs
// You could extract a method which takes the userInfoService user as an argument, see `findUser` below.
    user = userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(userInfoService.getUser().getLogin(),userInfoService.getUser().getPassword()).get();

// the above would then  become:
    User user = findUser(userInfoService.getUser()).orElseThrow(new ShoppingServiceException("User not found");

// instead of clearing these field, just initialize them as local variables:       
    shoppingList.clear();
    meals.clear();

    meals = user.getDiet().getMeals();

// I would change adjustIngredients so it doesn't return the meals but void
// it's expected that such a method modifies the meals without making a copy
    meals = dietMealsService.adjustIngredients(meals);

// I would extract the below iteration into a separate method for clarity
    for (MealInfo meal : meals) {

// I would also extract the processing of a single meal into a separate method
// the `meal.getIngredients` actually doesn't return Ingredients but IngredientWeights
// this is very confusing, I would rename the field to `ingredientWeights`
        meal.getMeal().getIngredients().forEach(s -> {
// I would replace the four calls to s.getIngredient() with one call and a local variable
// and probably extract another method here
// You are using Ingredient as the key of a Map so you must implement
// `equals` and // `hashCode`. Otherwise you will be in for nasty 
// surprises later when Java doesn't see your identical ingredients as 
// equal. The simplest would be to use the database ID to determine equality.
            if(shoppingList.containsKey(s.getIngredient()))
                shoppingList.put(s.getIngredient(), s.getWeight()+shoppingList.get(s.getIngredient()));
            else
            shoppingList.put(s.getIngredient(),s.getWeight());
        });
    }
    return shoppingList;
}


private Optional<User> findUser(my.service.User user) {
    if (user != null) {
        return userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword());
    }
    else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

private void processMeals(List<MealInfo> meals, Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList) {
    for (MealInfo mealInfo : meals) {
        processIngredientWeights(mealInfo.getMeal().getIngredients(), shoppingList);
    }
}

private void processIngredientWeights(List<IngredientWeight> ingredientWeights, Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList) {
    for (IngredientWeight ingredientWeight: ingredientWeights) {            
        processIngredientWeight(ingredientWeight, shoppingList);
    }
}

private void processIngredientWeight(IngredientWeight ingredientWeight, Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList) {          
    Ingredient ingredient = ingredientWeight.getIngredient();
    Long weight = shoppingList.getOrDefault(ingredient, 0L);
    weight += ingredientWeight.getWeight();
    shoppingList.put(ingredient, weight);
}
```

EDIT: I looked at your code and domain again and made some changes, see my example code here: https://github.com/akoster/x-converter/blob/master/src/main/java/xcon/stackoverflow/shopping

The domain model was a bit confusing because of the 'Info' classes. I renamed them as follows:

```
MealInfo -> Meal
Meal -> Recipe (with a list of Ingredients)
IngredientInfo -> Ingredient (represents a certain amount of a FoodItem)
Ingredient -> FoodItem (e.g. 'broccoli')
```

I realized that the service took no arguments! That's a bit odd. It makes sense to get the user separately (e.g. depending on the currently logged in/selected user) and pass it into the service, as you see above. The ShoppingListService now looks like this:

```
public class ShoppingListService {

    private DietMealsService dietMealsService;

    public ShoppingListService(DietMealsService dietMealsService) {
        this.dietMealsService = dietMealsService;
    }

    public ShoppingList createShoppingList(User user) {
        List<Meal> meals = getMeals(user);
        dietMealsService.adjustIngredients(meals);
        return createShoppingList(meals);
    }

    private List<Meal> getMeals(User user) {
        Diet diet = user.getDiet();
        if (diet == null || diet.getMeals() == null || diet.getMeals().isEmpty()) {
            throw new ShoppingServiceException("User doesn't have diet");
        }
        return diet.getMeals();
    }

    private ShoppingList createShoppingList(List<Meal> meals) {
        ShoppingList shoppingList = new ShoppingList();
        for (Meal meal : meals) {
            processIngredientWeights(meal.getRecipe().getIngredients(), shoppingList);
        }
        return shoppingList;
    }

    private void processIngredientWeights(List<Ingredient> ingredients, ShoppingList shoppingList) {
        for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients) {
            shoppingList.addWeight(ingredient);
        }
    }

}
```

I also introduced a 'ShoppingList' class because passing a Map around is a code smell and now I could move the logic to add an ingredient to the shopping list into that class.

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ShoppingList {

    private final Map<FoodItem, Long> ingredientWeights = new HashMap<>();

    public void addWeight(Ingredient ingredient) {
        FoodItem foodItem = ingredient.getFoodItem();
        Long weight = ingredientWeights.getOrDefault(foodItem, 0L);
        weight += ingredient.getWeight();
        ingredientWeights.put(foodItem, weight);
    }
}
```

The unit test for this service now looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ShoppingListServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ShoppingListService instanceUnderTest;

    @Mock
    private DietMealsService dietMealsService;
    @Mock
    private User user;
    @Mock
    private Diet diet;
    @Mock
    private Meal meal;

    @Test(expected = ShoppingServiceException.class)
    public void testCreateShoppingListUserDietNull() {
        // SETUP
        User user = mock(User.class);
        when(user.getDiet()).thenReturn(null);

        // CALL
        instanceUnderTest.createShoppingList(user);
    }

    @Test(expected = ShoppingServiceException.class)
    public void testCreateShoppingListUserDietMealsNull() {
        // SETUP
        when(user.getDiet()).thenReturn(diet);
        when(diet.getMeals()).thenReturn(null);

        // CALL
        instanceUnderTest.createShoppingList(user);
    }

    @Test(expected = ShoppingServiceException.class)
    public void testCreateShoppingListUserDietMealsEmpty() {
        // SETUP
        when(user.getDiet()).thenReturn(diet);
        List<Meal> meals = new ArrayList<>();
        when(diet.getMeals()).thenReturn(meals);

        // CALL
        instanceUnderTest.createShoppingList(user);
    }


    @Test
    public void testCreateShoppingListAdjustsIngredients() {
        // SETUP
        when(user.getDiet()).thenReturn(diet);
        List<Meal> meals = Collections.singletonList(meal);
        when(diet.getMeals()).thenReturn(meals);

        // CALL
        instanceUnderTest.createShoppingList(user);

        // VERIFY
        verify(dietMealsService).adjustIngredients(meals);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateShoppingListAddsWeights() {
        // SETUP
        when(user.getDiet()).thenReturn(diet);
        when(diet.getMeals()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(meal));
        Recipe recipe = mock(Recipe.class);
        when(meal.getRecipe()).thenReturn(recipe);
        Ingredient ingredient1 = mock(Ingredient.class);
        Ingredient ingredient2 = mock(Ingredient.class);
        when(recipe.getIngredients()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(ingredient1, ingredient2));
        FoodItem foodItem = mock(FoodItem.class);
        when(ingredient1.getFoodItem()).thenReturn(foodItem);
        when(ingredient2.getFoodItem()).thenReturn(foodItem);
        Long weight1 = 42L;
        Long weight2 = 1337L;
        when(ingredient1.getWeight()).thenReturn(weight1);
        when(ingredient2.getWeight()).thenReturn(weight2);

        // CALL
        ShoppingList shoppingList = instanceUnderTest.createShoppingList(user);

        // VERIFY
        Long expectedWeight = weight1 + weight2;
        Long actualWeight = shoppingList.getIngredientWeights().get(foodItem);
        assertEquals(expectedWeight, actualWeight);
    }
}
```

I hope that's pretty self-explanatory.

BTW remember that a unit test should only test the class under test. Try to minimize any assumptions about behavior of other classes and make that explicit by mocking them, as shown above. For the same reason I always try to avoid using 'realistic' test data in unit tests because it suggests that the values matter to the test - they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my design like Adrian said, and created a test to this method. Regarding to my code below, I have a few questions:

1. What do you think about my tests? The first section in `setUp` method and above is necessary or can I replace it somehow better? Maybe can I create an example entity in the database only for a test?
2. What more cases should I test?
3. Is it ok to extract `user.getDiet()` to separate method `checkDiet()` and using try-catch inside?
4. Why I get ShoppingServiceException("User not found") when I remove `login` and `password` fields from my variable `user` though I mock behavior of methods here `when(userInfoService.getUser()).thenReturn(user);
   when(userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));`

My refactored ShoppingServiceClass:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor

public class ShoppingListService {

    UserInfoService userInfoService;
    DietMealsService dietMealsService;
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ShoppingListService(UserInfoService userInfoService, DietMealsService dietMealsService,UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userInfoService = userInfoService;
        this.dietMealsService = dietMealsService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    public Map<Ingredient,Long> createShoppingList() throws ShoppingServiceException {
        User user = findUser(userInfoService.getUser()).orElseThrow(() -> new ShoppingServiceException("User not found"));
        List<MealInfo> meals = checkDiet(user).getMeals();
        dietMealsService.adjustMealsIngredients(meals);
        Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList = new HashMap<>();
        processMeals(meals, shoppingList);
        return shoppingList;
    }

    private Optional<User> findUser(User user) {
        if (user != null) {
            return userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword());
        }
        else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private Diet checkDiet(User user){
        try{
            user.getDiet().getMeals();
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            throw new ShoppingServiceException("User doesn't have diet");
        }
        return user.getDiet();
    }

    private void processMeals(List<MealInfo> meals, Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList) {
        for (MealInfo mealInfo : meals) {
            processIngredientWeights(mealInfo.getMeal().getIngredientWeights(), shoppingList);
        }
    }

    private void processIngredientWeights(List<IngredientWeight> ingredientWeights, Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList) {
        for (IngredientWeight ingredientWeight: ingredientWeights) {
            processIngredientWeight(ingredientWeight, shoppingList);
        }
    }

    private void processIngredientWeight(IngredientWeight ingredientWeight, Map<Ingredient, Long> shoppingList) {
        Ingredient ingredient = ingredientWeight.getIngredient();
        Long weight = shoppingList.getOrDefault(ingredient, 0L);
        weight += ingredientWeight.getWeight();
        shoppingList.put(ingredient, weight);
    }

}
```

And ShoppingServiceTest class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ShoppingListServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ShoppingListService shoppingListService;

    @Mock
    UserInfoService userInfoService;

    @Mock
    DietMealsService dietMealsService;

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    private Ingredient pineapple;
    private Ingredient bread;
    private Ingredient butter;
    private IngredientWeight pineappleWeight;
    private IngredientWeight bread1Weight;
    private IngredientWeight bread2Weight;
    private IngredientWeight butterWeight;
    private Meal meal1;
    private Meal meal2;
    private Meal meal3;
    private MealInfo mealInfo1;
    private MealInfo mealInfo2;
    private MealInfo mealInfo3;
    private Diet diet;
    private User user;
    private User user2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        //Ingredient
        pineapple = new Ingredient();
        pineapple.setName("Pineapple");
        bread = new Ingredient();
        bread.setName("Bread");
        butter = new Ingredient();
        butter.setName("Butter");

        //IngredientWeight
        pineappleWeight = new IngredientWeight();
        pineappleWeight.setIngredient(pineapple);
        pineappleWeight.setWeight(200L);
        bread1Weight = new IngredientWeight();
        bread1Weight.setIngredient(bread);
        bread1Weight.setWeight(300L);
        bread2Weight = new IngredientWeight();
        bread2Weight.setIngredient(bread);
        bread2Weight.setWeight(200L);
        butterWeight = new IngredientWeight();
        butterWeight.setIngredient(butter);
        butterWeight.setWeight(50L);

        //Meal
        meal1 = new Meal();
        meal1.setIngredientWeights(Arrays.asList(bread1Weight,butterWeight));
        meal2 = new Meal();
        meal2.setIngredientWeights(Arrays.asList(pineappleWeight,bread2Weight));
        meal3 = new Meal();
        meal3.setIngredientWeights(Arrays.asList(butterWeight,bread2Weight));

        //MealInfo
        mealInfo1 = new MealInfo();
        mealInfo1.setMeal(meal1);
        mealInfo1.setName("Posiłek 1"); //Meal 1
        mealInfo2 = new MealInfo();
        mealInfo2.setMeal(meal2);
        mealInfo2.setName("Posiłek 2"); //Meal 2
        mealInfo3 = new MealInfo();
        mealInfo3.setMeal(meal3);
        mealInfo3.setName("Posiłek 3"); //Meal 3

        //Diet
        diet = new Diet();
        diet.setMeals(Arrays.asList(mealInfo1,mealInfo2,mealInfo3));

        //User
        user = new User();
        user.setDiet(diet);
        user.setLogin("123");
        user.setPassword("123");

        //User
        user2 = new User();
        user2.setLogin("123");
        user2.setPassword("123");

    }

    @Test(expected = ShoppingServiceException.class)
    public void shouldThrownShoppingServiceExceptionWhenUserNotFound() throws ShoppingServiceException {

        shoppingListService.createShoppingList();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnShoppingListWhenUserHasDiet(){

        when(userInfoService.getUser()).thenReturn(user);
        when(userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
        doNothing().when(dietMealsService).adjustMealsIngredients(anyList());
        Map<Ingredient,Long> expectedResult = new HashMap<>();
        expectedResult.put(pineapple, 200L);
        expectedResult.put(bread, 700L);
        expectedResult.put(butter,100L);
        Map<Ingredient,Long> actualResult = shoppingListService.createShoppingList();
        assertEquals(actualResult,expectedResult);

    }

    @Test(expected = ShoppingServiceException.class)
    public void shouldReturnShoppingServiceExceptionWhenUserDoesntHaveDiet(){

        when(userInfoService.getUser()).thenReturn(user2);
        when(userRepository.findByLoginAndPassword(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user2));
        doNothing().when(dietMealsService).adjustMealsIngredients(anyList());
        Map<Ingredient,Long> expectedResult = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Ingredient,Long> actualResult = shoppingListService.createShoppingList();
        assertEquals(actualResult,expectedResult);

    }
}
```